# zwave-js-ui mqtt - how to translate nodeId to node's text name

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, z-wave

I'm trialing a Zwave setup, with an Aeotec temp/humidity sensor, an aeotec stick - Z-stick 7 and `zwave-js-ui` (https://zwave-js.github.io/zwave-js-ui/#/guide/mqtt)

I have `mosquitto` mqtt broker. In `zwave-js-ui`, I've prefixed the service `zwave` in `Settings->MQTT->prefix`. In `Control panel` I've named my sensor `aeotec-temp-rh-sensor1`. I subscribe to mqtt using `mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t zwave/#`

Here is the output to `mosquitto` when for example I press the button on the sensor:

```
{"value":"9.0.3","time":1697136643281}
{"value":true,"time":1697136643282}
true
{"time":1697136646138,"value":true,"status":"Unknown","nodeId":1}
{"time":1697136646139,"value":true,"status":"Unknown","nodeId":3}
{"time":1697136646140,"value":true,"status":"Alive","nodeId":1}
{"time":1697136646142,"value":true,"status":"Alive","nodeId":1}
{"time":1697136646143,"value":true,"status":"Asleep","nodeId":3}
{"id":"3-48-0-General Purpose","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":48,"commandClassName":"Binary Sensor","endpoint":0,"property":"General Purpose","propertyName":"General Purpose","type":"boolean","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Sensor state (General Purpose)","ccSpecific":{"sensorType":1},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":2,"list":false,"value":false,"lastUpdate":1697044106587}
{"id":"3-49-0-Air temperature","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":49,"commandClassName":"Multilevel Sensor","endpoint":0,"property":"Air temperature","propertyName":"Air temperature","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Air temperature","ccSpecific":{"sensorType":1,"scale":0},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":11,"unit":"°C","list":false,"value":22.1,"lastUpdate":1697136466820}
{"id":"3-49-0-Humidity","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":49,"commandClassName":"Multilevel Sensor","endpoint":0,"property":"Humidity","propertyName":"Humidity","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Humidity","ccSpecific":{"sensorType":5,"scale":0},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":11,"unit":"%","list":false,"value":54,"lastUpdate":1697136466839}
{"id":"3-49-0-Dew point","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":49,"commandClassName":"Multilevel Sensor","endpoint":0,"property":"Dew point","propertyName":"Dew point","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Dew point","ccSpecific":{"sensorType":11,"scale":0},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":11,"unit":"°C","list":false,"value":12.3,"lastUpdate":1697136466851}
{"id":"3-112-0-1","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":1,"propertyName":"Temperature Change Report Threshold","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Temperature Change Report Threshold","default":20,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":100,"unit":"0.1 °(C/F)","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":20,"lastUpdate":1697044108099}
{"id":"3-112-0-2","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":2,"propertyName":"Humidity Change Report Threshold","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Humidity Change Report Threshold","default":5,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":20,"unit":"%","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":5,"lastUpdate":1697044107558}
{"id":"3-112-0-3","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":3,"propertyName":"Threshold Check Interval","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Threshold Check Interval","default":15,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":1,"max":255,"unit":"minutes","list":false,"value":15,"lastUpdate":1697044107590}
{"id":"3-112-0-4","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":4,"propertyName":"Automatic Reporting Interval","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Allowable Range: 30-65535","label":"Automatic Reporting Interval","default":43200,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":65535,"unit":"seconds","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":43200,"lastUpdate":1697044107623}
{"id":"3-112-0-5","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":5,"propertyName":"High Temperature Basic Set Threshold","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"High Temperature Basic Set Threshold","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":1000,"unit":"0.1 °(C/F)","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107654}
{"id":"3-112-0-10","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":10,"propertyName":"High Temperature Basic Set Value","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Allowable Range: 0-99, 255.","label":"High Temperature Basic Set Value","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107684}
{"id":"3-112-0-6","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":6,"propertyName":"Low Temperature Basic Set Threshold","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Low Temperature Basic Set Threshold","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":-200,"max":1000,"unit":"0.1 °(C/F)","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107715}
{"id":"3-112-0-9","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":9,"propertyName":"Low Temperature Basic Set Value","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Allowable Range: 0-99, 255.","label":"Low Temperature Basic Set Value","default":255,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"value":255,"lastUpdate":1697044107751}
{"id":"3-112-0-7","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":7,"propertyName":"High Humidity Basic Set Threshold","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"High Humidity Basic Set Threshold","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":90,"unit":"%","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107782}
{"id":"3-112-0-16","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":16,"propertyName":"Check Interval for Parameter 5, 6, 7, 8","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Check Interval for Parameter 5, 6, 7, 8","default":15,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":1,"max":255,"unit":"minutes","list":false,"value":15,"lastUpdate":1697044107811}
{"id":"3-112-0-12","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":12,"propertyName":"High Humidity Trigger Basic Set Value","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Allowable Range: 0-99, 255.","label":"High Humidity Trigger Basic Set Value","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107848}
{"id":"3-112-0-8","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":8,"propertyName":"Low Humidity Basic Set Threshold","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Low Humidity Basic Set Threshold","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":90,"unit":"%","list":true,"allowManualEntry":true,"states":[{"text":"Disable","value":0}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107880}
{"id":"3-112-0-11","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":11,"propertyName":"Low Humidity Trigger Basic Set Value","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Allowable Range: 0-99, 255.","label":"Low Humidity Trigger Basic Set Value","default":255,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"value":255,"lastUpdate":1697044107910}
{"id":"3-112-0-13","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":13,"propertyName":"Humidity Offset for Mold Danger Notification","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Humidity Offset for Mold Danger Notification","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":10,"unit":"%","list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107941}
{"id":"3-112-0-14","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":14,"propertyName":"Temperature Calibration","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Temperature Calibration","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":-200,"max":200,"unit":"0.1 °(C/F)","list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044107975}
{"id":"3-112-0-15","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":15,"propertyName":"Humidity Calibration","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Humidity Calibration","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":-50,"max":50,"unit":"%","list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044108008}
{"id":"3-112-0-65-1","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":65,"propertyName":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Battery","propertyKey":1,"type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Battery","default":1,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":1,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044108039}
{"id":"3-112-0-65-2","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":65,"propertyName":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Temperature","propertyKey":2,"type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Temperature","default":1,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":1,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044108039}
{"id":"3-112-0-65-4","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":65,"propertyName":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Humidity","propertyKey":4,"type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Humidity","default":1,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":1,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044108040}
{"id":"3-112-0-65-8","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":65,"propertyName":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Dew Point","propertyKey":8,"type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Sensor Report after Inclusion: Dew Point","default":1,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":1,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044108040}
{"id":"3-112-0-64","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":64,"propertyName":"Temperature Unit","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Temperature Unit","default":1,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":1,"max":2,"list":true,"allowManualEntry":false,"states":[{"text":"Celsius","value":1},{"text":"Fahrenheit","value":2}],"value":1,"lastUpdate":1697044108070}
{"id":"3-112-0-92","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":92,"propertyName":"Battery Calibration Check","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"To determine the battery calibration value, set each step in order and wait for the value to update. If the returned values are NOT 0, the battery is still calibrated.","label":"Battery Calibration Check","default":83951616,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":83951616,"max":84082688,"list":true,"allowManualEntry":false,"states":[{"text":"Step 1","value":83951616},{"text":"Step 2","value":84017152},{"text":"Step 3","value":84082688}],"lastUpdate":1697136646157}
{"id":"3-112-0-255","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":112,"commandClassName":"Configuration","endpoint":0,"property":255,"propertyName":"Reset to Factory Default Setting","type":"number","readable":false,"writeable":true,"label":"Reset to Factory Default Setting","default":0,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":4,"min":0,"max":4294967295,"list":true,"allowManualEntry":false,"states":[{"text":"Normal operation","value":0},{"text":"Reset all configuration parameters to default settings","value":1},{"text":"Completely factory reset sensor and send device reset locally notification","value":4294967295}],"lastUpdate":1697136646157}
{"id":"3-113-0-Heat Alarm-Heat sensor status","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":113,"commandClassName":"Notification","endpoint":0,"property":"Heat Alarm","propertyName":"Heat Alarm","propertyKey":"Heat sensor status","propertyKeyName":"Heat sensor status","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Heat sensor status","ccSpecific":{"notificationType":4},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":8,"min":0,"max":255,"list":true,"states":[{"text":"idle","value":0},{"text":"Overheat detected","value":2},{"text":"Underheat detected","value":6}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044109330}
{"id":"3-113-0-Power Management-Battery maintenance status","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":113,"commandClassName":"Notification","endpoint":0,"property":"Power Management","propertyName":"Power Management","propertyKey":"Battery maintenance status","propertyKeyName":"Battery maintenance status","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Battery maintenance status","ccSpecific":{"notificationType":8},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":8,"min":0,"max":255,"list":true,"states":[{"text":"idle","value":0},{"text":"Replace battery now","value":11}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044109371}
{"id":"3-113-0-Weather Alarm-Moisture alarm status","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":113,"commandClassName":"Notification","endpoint":0,"property":"Weather Alarm","propertyName":"Weather Alarm","propertyKey":"Moisture alarm status","propertyKeyName":"Moisture alarm status","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Moisture alarm status","ccSpecific":{"notificationType":16},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":8,"min":0,"max":255,"list":true,"states":[{"text":"idle","value":0},{"text":"Moisture alarm","value":2}],"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044109405}
{"id":"3-113-0-alarmType","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":113,"commandClassName":"Notification","endpoint":0,"property":"alarmType","propertyName":"alarmType","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Alarm Type","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":8,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"lastUpdate":1697136646157}
{"id":"3-113-0-alarmLevel","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":113,"commandClassName":"Notification","endpoint":0,"property":"alarmLevel","propertyName":"alarmLevel","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Alarm Level","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":8,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"lastUpdate":1697136646158}
{"id":"3-114-0-manufacturerId","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":114,"commandClassName":"Manufacturer Specific","endpoint":0,"property":"manufacturerId","propertyName":"manufacturerId","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Manufacturer ID","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":2,"min":0,"max":65535,"list":false,"value":881,"lastUpdate":1697044104209}
{"id":"3-114-0-productType","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":114,"commandClassName":"Manufacturer Specific","endpoint":0,"property":"productType","propertyName":"productType","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Product type","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":2,"min":0,"max":65535,"list":false,"value":2,"lastUpdate":1697044104210}
{"id":"3-114-0-productId","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":114,"commandClassName":"Manufacturer Specific","endpoint":0,"property":"productId","propertyName":"productId","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Product ID","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":2,"min":0,"max":65535,"list":false,"value":9,"lastUpdate":1697044104211}
{"id":"3-128-0-level","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":128,"commandClassName":"Battery","endpoint":0,"property":"level","propertyName":"level","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Battery level","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":1,"min":0,"max":100,"unit":"%","list":false,"value":100,"lastUpdate":1697044105370}
{"id":"3-128-0-isLow","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":128,"commandClassName":"Battery","endpoint":0,"property":"isLow","propertyName":"isLow","type":"boolean","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Low battery level","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":1,"list":false,"value":false,"lastUpdate":1697044105370}
{"id":"3-132-0-wakeUpInterval","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":132,"commandClassName":"Wake Up","endpoint":0,"property":"wakeUpInterval","propertyName":"wakeUpInterval","type":"number","readable":false,"writeable":true,"label":"wakeUpInterval (property)","default":604800,"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":2,"min":3600,"max":15724800,"step":240,"list":false,"value":604800,"lastUpdate":1697044105189}
{"id":"3-132-0-controllerNodeId","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":132,"commandClassName":"Wake Up","endpoint":0,"property":"controllerNodeId","propertyName":"controllerNodeId","type":"any","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Node ID of the controller","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":2,"list":false,"value":1,"lastUpdate":1697044105224}
{"id":"3-134-0-libraryType","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"libraryType","propertyName":"libraryType","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Library type","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":true,"states":[{"text":"Unknown","value":0},{"text":"Static Controller","value":1},{"text":"Controller","value":2},{"text":"Enhanced Slave","value":3},{"text":"Slave","value":4},{"text":"Installer","value":5},{"text":"Routing Slave","value":6},{"text":"Bridge Controller","value":7},{"text":"Device under Test","value":8},{"text":"N/A","value":9},{"text":"AV Remote","value":10},{"text":"AV Device","value":11}],"value":3,"lastUpdate":1697044104313}
{"id":"3-134-0-protocolVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"protocolVersion","propertyName":"protocolVersion","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave protocol version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":"7.15","lastUpdate":1697044104314}
{"id":"3-134-0-firmwareVersions","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"firmwareVersions","propertyName":"firmwareVersions","type":"string[]","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave chip firmware versions","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":["2.3"],"lastUpdate":1697044104316}
{"id":"3-134-0-hardwareVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"hardwareVersion","propertyName":"hardwareVersion","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave chip hardware version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":1,"lastUpdate":1697044104317}
{"id":"3-134-0-sdkVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"sdkVersion","propertyName":"sdkVersion","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"SDK version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":"7.15.4","lastUpdate":1697044105031}
{"id":"3-134-0-applicationFrameworkAPIVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"applicationFrameworkAPIVersion","propertyName":"applicationFrameworkAPIVersion","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave application framework API version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":"10.15.4","lastUpdate":1697044105032}
{"id":"3-134-0-applicationFrameworkBuildNumber","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"applicationFrameworkBuildNumber","propertyName":"applicationFrameworkBuildNumber","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave application framework API build number","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":256,"lastUpdate":1697044105032}
{"id":"3-134-0-hostInterfaceVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"hostInterfaceVersion","propertyName":"hostInterfaceVersion","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Serial API version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":"unused","lastUpdate":1697044105033}
{"id":"3-134-0-hostInterfaceBuildNumber","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"hostInterfaceBuildNumber","propertyName":"hostInterfaceBuildNumber","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Serial API build number","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044105034}
{"id":"3-134-0-zWaveProtocolVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"zWaveProtocolVersion","propertyName":"zWaveProtocolVersion","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave protocol version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":"7.15.4","lastUpdate":1697044105035}
{"id":"3-134-0-zWaveProtocolBuildNumber","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"zWaveProtocolBuildNumber","propertyName":"zWaveProtocolBuildNumber","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Z-Wave protocol build number","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":256,"lastUpdate":1697044105036}
{"id":"3-134-0-applicationVersion","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"applicationVersion","propertyName":"applicationVersion","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Application version","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":"2.3.1","lastUpdate":1697044105037}
{"id":"3-134-0-applicationBuildNumber","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":134,"commandClassName":"Version","endpoint":0,"property":"applicationBuildNumber","propertyName":"applicationBuildNumber","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":false,"label":"Application build number","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":43707,"lastUpdate":1697044105038}
{"id":"3-135-0-80-3","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":135,"commandClassName":"Indicator","endpoint":0,"property":80,"propertyName":"Node Identify","propertyKey":3,"propertyKeyName":"On/Off Period: Duration","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Sets the duration of an on/off period in 1/10th seconds. Must be set together with \"On/Off Cycle Count\"","label":"Node Identify - On/Off Period: Duration","ccSpecific":{"indicatorId":80,"propertyId":3},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044105332}
{"id":"3-135-0-80-4","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":135,"commandClassName":"Indicator","endpoint":0,"property":80,"propertyName":"Node Identify","propertyKey":4,"propertyKeyName":"On/Off Cycle Count","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"Sets the number of on/off periods. 0xff means infinite. Must be set together with \"On/Off Period duration\"","label":"Node Identify - On/Off Cycle Count","ccSpecific":{"indicatorId":80,"propertyId":4},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044105333}
{"id":"3-135-0-80-5","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":135,"commandClassName":"Indicator","endpoint":0,"property":80,"propertyName":"Node Identify","propertyKey":5,"propertyKeyName":"On/Off Period: On time","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"description":"This property is used to set the length of the On time during an On/Off period. It allows asymmetric On/Off periods. The value 0x00 MUST represent symmetric On/Off period (On time equal to Off time)","label":"Node Identify - On/Off Period: On time","ccSpecific":{"indicatorId":80,"propertyId":5},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"value":0,"lastUpdate":1697044105334}
{"id":"3-135-0-value","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":135,"commandClassName":"Indicator","endpoint":0,"property":"value","propertyName":"value","type":"number","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Indicator value","ccSpecific":{"indicatorId":0},"stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"min":0,"max":255,"list":false,"lastUpdate":1697136646160}
{"id":"3-135-0-identify","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":135,"commandClassName":"Indicator","endpoint":0,"property":"identify","propertyName":"identify","type":"boolean","readable":false,"writeable":true,"label":"Identify","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":true,"states":[{"text":"Identify","value":true}],"lastUpdate":1697136646160}
{"id":"3-135-0-timeout","nodeId":3,"toUpdate":false,"commandClass":135,"commandClassName":"Indicator","endpoint":0,"property":"timeout","propertyName":"timeout","type":"string","readable":true,"writeable":true,"label":"Timeout","stateless":false,"commandClassVersion":3,"list":false,"lastUpdate":1697136646160}
{"time":1697136646161,"value":true,"status":"Asleep","nodeId":3}
```

So, buried in all this we have, e.g.
`{"id":"3-49-0-Air temperature","nodeId":3, "property": "Air temperature", "value": 23.1}`

So, I know this is my sensor (`"nodeId":3`) as the network only has one node and the gateway has `"nodeId": 1`. But I was hoping that somewhere there would be a link from `"nodeId":3` to the text name I've given the node in `zwave-js-ui`, i.e. `aeotec-temp-rh-sensor1`?

Any help appreciated - I only want the sensor name, temperature and humidity for now, not interested in the rest ...